MATLAB: Deploying Optimfunctions to Standalone C/C++ Code
I am looking to deploy a function i have created that uses optimvars and optimproblems to a comuter that does not have MATLAB installed by creating a .exe file with the MATLAB Coder. However, optimvars and optimproblems are not supported for code generation.
Are there other methods to deploy these functions or are there alternative functions that provide similar functionality to the optimisation problem toolbox that are compatible with the compiler?

Most optimalization functions and optimoptions are compatible with code generation. Can you rewrite the problem in a solver based problem? that should allow you to generate code.

Do you have access to the MATLAB Compiler? With that you can turn any MATLAB code into an executable or a shared library (DLL).

I had wanted to make it standallone and not require someone to download the Matlab Compiler Runtime but it looks like you can put the install for that in the folder when you use the Matlab Compiler App which seems to be the easiest solution
